# Primary key violation error code using ODBC with MS Access

Tags: java, ms-access, odbc, primary-key

I am using Java with Microsoft Access through an ODBC driver. When I insert a duplicate entry for primary key it gives me an error: `java.sql.SQLException: General error`. I want to show a message to the user that this record already exists, but I think that this exception can be thrown by ODBC in some other cases also. So I found that there are error codes against each message ([ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms714687%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), but I found no error code for primary key violation. Can anyone tell me what error code is for primary key violation for ODBC with MS Access?

Here is basic code

```
String qry = "INSERT INTO customers VALUES ('" + txtReg.getText()
            + "' ,'" + txtName.getText() + "', '" + txtCity.getText() + "' ,'" + txtCell.getText() + "')";

try {

    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:MyDB");

    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    st.executeQuery(qry);
    st.close();
    con.close();

} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error: " + ex, "Error!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error: " + ex, "Error!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

These `txtName` and so on are `JTextFields`. Here is complete Stack trace

```
connected
st created

Error code: 0
SQLState: S1000
Messsage: General error

java.sql.SQLException: General error
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6986)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7114)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecDirect(JdbcOdbc.java:3110)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.execute(JdbcOdbcStatement.java:338)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcOdbcStatement.java:288)
    at gui.InsertFileCode.btnInsertActionPerformed(insertFileCode.java:399)
```

Comment: Could you add your code please.

Comment: 'Azad' I added the code.

Comment: See the answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in this line  `st.executeQuery(qry);`

`executeQuery(query)` method is used mostly for SELECT statement and it returns the in form of ResultSet object.

Sence the statement is INSERT statement you have to use `executeUpdate(query)` , this method is generally used by INSERT, UPDATE,  And DELETE statements. When table updated successfully then it returns 1.
For example

```
int result = st.executeUpdate(qry);
System.out.println(result);
```

---

## UPDATE:

Due to the comments, I've fegured out you have another problem rather than the SQL statement. You must beware of when using *java to Ms Access*, you're actually connecting to a middleware server, so that, you must expect un-expected exception(s) while running the *SQL* statement, for example:

> CRATE TABLE FOO (ID varchar (50) NOT NULL , NAME varchar (255) DEFAULT NULL)

This query runs on SQLite and MySQL (maybe SQL Server too as I didn't test it), gives  **Syntex error** on *Access*, as `DEFAULT NULL`  should be removed for running the statement.A nd maybe there are many other problem you have to prepare facing it with Access "database" file.

So, I am telling you to leave it, MS Access is suitable for its users, not for us as a programmer, we have to find best-general way because we must consider that some user uses this application that don't know anything neither about *Programming Language nor Database*.

## Then, what should I do?

I am not an expert in database, but take my advice :

- If your application need to share its database: **MySQL, Oracle and SQL Server** used for that  purpose.
- If your application is used only for some purposes and not need to share its records to other users, use an actually serverless database engine such as **SQLite**. This seems to be the best option for you as it's a file like Access, only needs an external driver for Java, see [this](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc).

I think there is a FireFox extension for designing the SQLite database if you search on google maybe you find it.

Comment: It did not solved the problem. Still the same error occurs when I give duplicate key value. My problem is to know what is error code for ODBC MS Access when it received a query with PK violation. Thanks for mentioning `finally` but I am already using this, but I did not write here for code simplicity. I am pasting complete stack trace. May be this is helpful.

Comment: Is `st.executeUpdate(qry)` returns value other than 1 if it find a PK violation? But I debugged the code it jumps to the `SQLException catch block` when it reaches the `st.executeUpdate(qry);` statement. Means this statement is throwing the exception. I pasted the stack trace by using `st.executeUpdate(qry)`

Comment: Yes, I was confused because you didn't mention your code were for demonstration that's why I corrected it.

Comment: About the `general error`, it's hard to say what causes this problem, maybe some java exception which is bundled and displayed as general error, or maybe a suitable mistake. 

There is a lot of things causes this error, sometimes data type, in your case, duplication primary key, that's why it's hard to tell.

Comment: Then how can I know that there is a violation of primary key?Any approach.

Comment: Yes, leave MS-Acees, if your application is large, use MySQL, otherwise, the use SQLite database. See the answer of [**this question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232755/how-to-connect-with-mysql-database-file-sql-using-directory-path-like-ms-acc) for more detail.

Comment: +1 Yes, I am also thinking the same that MS Access is so stupid. Thanks for Sqlite. I am building a small standalone application, is this a correct approach to use sqlite, I was using Access due to its file like features and no need for backup from OS drive? Is sqlite have same features?

Comment: Great! Yes database is not shared b\w any one. You are right problem is with `ODBC`, hhh at same time I found that executing the same query inside Access gives the proper error but not using ODBC, thanks any way. I want that there is never need for backup, even the OS crashes, as I placed the access file in the D: drive (any one other than OS). Can I do same with the sqlite? I searched but did not getting appropriate answer.

Comment: @aquestion: What do want is save the `.sqlite` file to **D:** drive? Yes, you can. And about how to it, you can ask a different question as maybe it will be useful also for someone else.

Comment: @ Azad: very helpful, I made a project from your answer